# How to check if variable have assigned value

Tags: c

Here is my code snippet

```
main() {

    char *filename;

    if(1 > 2) {
      filename = "file.txt"
     }

     if(filename != NULL (also tried 0) {
       do something
     }
     return 0;
    }
```

My question is how to check if filename var have assigned value. I can use strcmp but rvalue can be different of "file.txt"

Comment: Always initialize your variables! (pointers to `NULL`)

Comment: I have read somewhere that extern variables are automatically initialized to 0.

Comment: @user1074077: not in C or C++, but yes in Java and many other languages.

Comment: @user1074077: in `C`, static variables are, I believe, but it's good practice to always do it. Then you never have to wonder what value a variable has.

Comment: we can not definitely rely on 'variable will be automatically assigned to so and so'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change:

```
char *filename;
```

To:

```
char *filename = NULL;
```

Then your `NULL` tests will work.

When you don't initialize this pointer, its value is **undefined**.  That's why your tests were failing.  The compiler assumed that you didn't care what value it had.

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason this assignment is necessary is that C does not store any value in a variable's memory when it is allocated unless you provide one.

Comment: @maerics: I was just thinking the same thing.  Edited.

Comment: If you are using GCC, compiling with the `-Wuninitialized` option enabled will help catch these issues. Cf. http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_8.html

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the pointer yourself, it doesn't have a guaranteed starting value otherwise.

```
char *filename = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you declare (or define) a variable, initialize them to `0` or `NULL` (if pointers) and then check it against them!

For example,

```
int i = 0;

.. 
if (!i) {

}
```

For pointers,

```
int *p = NULL;

..
if (!p) {

}
```